# Native Client - how can I use GetTime?

Tags: compiler-errors, google-nativeclient, gettime

I am fairly new to NaCl and trying to port a successful application from C++ Visual Stidio. I want to get the time and my code has the following statement:

PP_Time mytime = PPB_Core::GetTime();

but the compiler does not like this giving the following error message:

object missing in reference to 'PPB_Core_1_0::GetTime'

This means nothing to me. Can somebody explain what it means and what I have to do to fix the problem?

Alan

Answer (score 0):

GetTime is an object member that points to a function, not the function name itself. Here is what compiles for me:

```
PP_Time mytime = pp::Module::Get()->core()->GetTime();
```